# Axon event handler and query handlers do not work together in kotlin

Tags: axon

Code:

```
@Component
open class UserProjectionQuery {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var repository: UserDocumentRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var updateEmitter: QueryUpdateEmitter

    @QueryHandler
    fun handle(query: QueryUserIdForUsername): String? {
       //stuff
    }

    @EventHandler
    fun on(evt: UserAuthenticated) {
       //stuff
    }
}
```

Apparently it doesn't inject my repository nor update emitter.
The event handler creates `AnnotationQueryHandlerAdapter` instead of `AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter`.

The solution atm is to move out the `@EventHandler`'s to separate class and keep them there while `@QueryHandler`'s in separate class too.

I remember it was working with java. I'm not sure what i'm missing here but it seems like it's a spring-kotlin bug? 
Any tip would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is weird. I'm sure that my example is working correctly with the similar use case

https://github.com/idugalic/digital-restaurant/blob/master/drestaurant-apps/drestaurant-microservices-rest/drestaurant-microservices-rest-restaurant/src/main/kotlin/com/drestaurant/query/handler/RestaurantHandler.kt

Consider using constructor to inject your dependencies (you will avoid `var` and `lateinit`)

```
class UserProjectionQuery(private val repository: UserDocumentRepository, private val updateEmitter: QueryUpdateEmitter)
```

You can also use maven plugin `kotlin-maven-plugin` to open all Spring configuration classes: https://github.com/idugalic/digital-restaurant/blob/master/pom.xml#L177